# How do I disassemble this faucet to replace the o-ring/cartridge?

Tags: kitchen-sink

My kitchen faucet is leaking from below the lever. I guess this is a cartridge/o-ring replacement case.

I removed the Allen screw to take out the lever. And now I am stuck.

I do not know the brand of the lever (installed by previous owners). I can't find it on the internet based on pictures.

So, per the information I see in the internet, I might need to remove the black piece/cap, but it doesn't seem to move (already added lubricant, tried with a wrench). I have also tried to rotate other parts (the 'neck') without success. BTW: I do not think I need to remove the top part, as my leak comes from the lever (I also tried to remove the top part unsuccessfully).

See pictures. Also, I do not know what the small hole pointed by the green arrow is. I tried to unscrew with different drivers to no avail (still, I do not think I need to disassemble that).

Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's "o-ring" not "o'ring". (Unless it's Irish.) ;)

Comment: Just a wild guess: have you tried twisting the outside metal part around the cartridge?

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate do you mean the black piece? or the stainless steel? (I have tried both).

Comment: I was thinking the stainless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to remove is the beveled ring around the front of the cartridge.

It may have flats or notches along the inside of the ring to help remove it. It unscrews counter-clockwise.
Once out the cartridge can be pulled out.  Then you can see if the o-ring is degraded, ( some applications do not have an o-ring and relies on the seals at the back of the cartridge.)

If a new cartridge is needed, look for the numbers on the side or back and google those.  Most all are able to be ordered online, some can be purchased locally.

Comment: The 'beveled ring' is the black ring... right? I have tried. I will keep trying. Thanks.

Comment: @rufo the red arrow [here](https://i.imgur.com/znvfjmY.jpg) is pointing at what looks like a flat. That might be a spot for either turning or prying. Or, it might just be a bit of damage from a previous try or a dirty spot...

Comment: @FreeMan that's damage I made trying to get it to rotate. But I guess the consensus is to try to rotate the black ring. Thanks.

Comment: It was the black ring. I used a wrench and it rotated (couter clockwise). I scratched it a bit, but that was it.